# How to fix No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate

I'm developping a web application using spring, hibernate and primefaces.

In this application I get data from a database and use it to display charts.

when I run my application I get this error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
```

This is the application context file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.6.SEC01.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.6.SEC01.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.6.SEC01.xsd
">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/biblio?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>root</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value></value>
        </property>

    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>Mapping/Status.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>Mapping/Authorities.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>Mapping/Livre.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>Mapping/Users.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>Mapping/Auteur.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>Mapping/Emprunteur.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>Mapping/Collection.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>Mapping/Emprunt.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>Mapping/Cathegorie.hbm.xml</value>

            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--Spring Data Access Exception Translator Defintion-->
    <bean id="jdbcExceptionTranslator" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator"  >
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!--Hibernate Template Defintion-->
    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate"  >
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jdbcExceptionTranslator">
            <ref bean="jdbcExceptionTranslator"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!--Hibernate Transaction Manager Definition-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"  >
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!--========================= Start of DAO BEANS DEFINITIONS =========================-->
    <bean id="autDao" class="Implementation.dao.AuteurDaoImpl"  >
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate"/>
    </bean> 
    <bean id="statusDao" class="Implementation.dao.StatusDaoImpl"  >
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="categDao" class="Implementation.dao.CategorieDaoImpl"  >
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate"/>
    </bean> 
    <bean id="empDao" class="Implementation.dao.EmprunteurDaoImpl"  >
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="colleDao" class="Implementation.dao.CollectionDaoImpl"  >
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="livDao" class="Implementation.dao.LivreDaoImpl"  >
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="emprDao" class="Implementation.dao.EmpruntDaoImpl"  >
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate"/>
    </bean>

    <!--========================= Start of SERVICE BEANS DEFINITIONS =========================-->
    <bean id="auDao" class="Implementation.service.AuteurServiceImpl"  >
        <property name="auteurDao" ref="autDao"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="statDao" class="Implementation.service.StatusServiceImpl"  >
        <property name="statusDao" ref="statusDao"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="catDao" class="Implementation.service.CategorieServiceImpl"  >
        <property name="categorieDao" ref="categDao"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="emprunDao" class="Implementation.service.EmprunteurServiceImpl"  >
        <property name="emprunteurDao" ref="empDao"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="collectionDao" class="Implementation.service.CollectionServiceImpl"  >
        <property name="collectionDao" ref="colleDao"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="livrDao" class="Implementation.service.LivreServiceImpl"  >
        <property name="livreDao" ref="livDao"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="empruDao" class="Implementation.service.EmpruntServiceImpl"  >
        <property name="empruntDao" ref="emprDao"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined - Spring Security 3.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132675/no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined-spring-security-3-1)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using spring security filter in your application.
Can you post your web.xml?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define in you web.xml

```
  filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```